# Find matrices of orthogonal projections onto all 4 fundamental subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Find matrices of orthogonal projections onto all 4 fundamental subspaces of the matrix A=

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
    2 & 4 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Ok since this is a 3 by 3 matrix, this is a transformation from R^3 to R^3. I know how to find the basis of the 4 fundamental subspace, but I don't think that is necessary. The formula for projection matrix onto the column space is $A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$ and if the vectors are orthonormal, it's just $AA^{T}$ since $(A^{T}A)^{-1}$ is just the identity. We just use that formula on A to find the projection onto the column space first.

I think we can make use of the fact that the left null space is orthogonal to the column space and null space is orthogonal to the column space. If P is the projection onto the column space, then I-P is the projection onto the left nullspace. Then we can do the same thing for the row space (by taking the transpose of the matrix and plugging it into the projection formula) and use I-P(row) to find the projection onto the null space.

I think this is probably the fastest way to solve this problem. Is there a faster way?

Edit: This matrix is not linearly full column rank so I need to find the basis for the column and row space. That is unavoidable, but after that we can use the formula for the nullspace and left nullspace.

Comment: I think the fastest is the following: If the space you want the projection for is $1$-dimensional and spanned by $v$, then the projection is $Px = \|v\|^{-2}\cdot\langle x,v\rangle v$. Put in the standard basis vectors, put the results into a matrix as columns and you're done. If the space is two-dimensional, find a vector perpendicular to it, find the corresponding projection $Q$ as above and then the matrix $I-Q$.

Comment: I just realized the columns are not linearly independent so we need to find the basis since A^TA is not invertible

Comment: If $A^TA$ is invertible, then $A$ is invertible and hence the column space is $\mathbb R^3$ and the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb R^3$ is the identity. Meaning your formula doesn't make much sense in this example.